# Run a set of code inside asynData function using Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

I have a chunk of code which needs to be repeated on around 20 pages inside asyncData() method on my NuxtJS based Project. So I want to create some kind of helper function that can return "logged_in_data". Problem is, it is using "await" in it, so I am not sure how the helper function will work. Any idea how I implement this helper function?

Below is my code:

```
let logged_in_user = null;
    if(process.client){
      console.log('>> client')
      logged_in_user = store.getters.loggedInUser
    }
    else{
      console.log('>> server')
      logged_in_user = await store.getters.getAuthenticatedUser
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call function in return method of async data.

```
asyncData (context) {
    return function1()
}

async function1(){
    await fisrtfunction()
    await secondfunction()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Although I used different solution. I just moved the if conditions inside the Vuex getter function instead :)
But thanks, this is also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `getter`, you can point to a null value that is assigned asynchronously and it will function when updated, but you should put it into `computed` instead.

```
computed: {
     return this.$store.getters.getAuthenticatedUser
    }
```

But here's the problem: if you have to await your getter, your design has an issue. For my Vue/Vuex application, I handle login this way:
- User logs in, and axios makes a call to the back-end to authenticate the user asynchronously (no store interaction)
- User is authenticated successfully and data comes from the database
- This data is committed to the store for easy access
- My getter points to the user data in the store (which is not asynchronous)

I highly recommend storing the user data upon authentication and pointing your getter there.